# how do you reference a class instance with a variable in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I've searched for an answer but can't find one. Maybe I'm just asking it the wrong way...

As an example, if I have a class as follows:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

I create a couple instances as follows and can get their attributes like this:

```
person1 = Person("John")
person2 = Person("Mike")
print person1.name
print person2.name
```

What I want to do is substitute "personX" with a variable, and this is the part I haven't figured out yet. I'd like to to use this to iterate through a list of names that map to class instances and get/set their attributes.

```
name1 = "person1"
print "%s".name % (name1) <--- this fails with "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Consider using a list or a map for storing the instances rather that individual variables - this way you can easily iterate over any number of those. Coming back to your original questions, `eval` could be used for getting a variable by name, but that should preferably be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you want to create `variableX` where `X` is an incrementing number, you really want a **list**:

```
people = []
people.append(Person('John'))
people.append(Person('Mike'))

for person in people:
    print person.name

print people[0].name
```

Comment: Or a dictionary, see below.

Comment: Why would I want `people['person0']` over `people[0]`. That's just redundant.

Comment: Well, he did after all want to map a name to a Person object.

Comment: If the "name" is just `"person1"`, then no, that's not really what they want.

Comment: He wanted a variable name, but `exec` is a bad option to do that. So a dictionary would be the best bet.

Comment: Sure, if the name actually matters and a key-value mapping is required, a dictionary is the answer. I simply don't see that from the given sample.

Comment: Thanks deceze. That's what I needed. Note the typo and that it should be "print poeple[0].name" in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval()` to get instance referenced by the created string this way

```py
name1 = "person1"
print eval(name1).name
```

Comment: don't use `eval()` if you can reasonably avoid it.

Comment: this solve his problem and can be the solution he's looking for.. but you'r wright

Comment: Don't take everything an OP asks literally if it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this is considered bad practice, especially with the use of `eval` and `exec` to do so:

```
people = {'person1': Person('Bob'), 'person2': Person('Sam')}
```